# Is there a more efficient way to plot csv file content?

Tags: python

I made a simple app to represent a chart from a csv file with python pandas and plot.
The file I use to plot out is a csv which is around 180kb with almost 6000 rows and two column's.
Nothing complex.

My question/problem is:
When I start the app to plot the chart, it takes to much time.
Around 20 - 30 sec which is I think to much time for such of small data.
I use Win10, i5, 8G ram, ssd...

This file is a log file which will grow day by day and I expect in one year to have a log file of around 1Mb.
I cant imagine does I should wait around 1min to read and plot the file of 1Mb one day.

What is wrong with this code or is there a better/faster/more effective way to process the data?
And if I use the zoom function on the plot it takes a loooot of time too.
It looks for me so buggy...

This is my function:

```
def plot_file(file_name):
    input_file = "log.csv"
    sample_data = pd.read_csv(input_file, names=["A", "B"], header=None)
    plt.plot(sample_data.A, sample_data.B)
    plt.title("File name: " + input_file)
    plt.xlabel("time scale x / date & time")
    plt.ylabel("quality scale y in %")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: We can't see where you import `matplotlib` and `pandas`. Maybe you run another hidden init task that consumes that long runtime? I suppose that the Python startup, module imports, CSV parsing and graph plotting should take together no more than 5sec on any modern PC

Comment: I tested it on my laptop with a similar 180k and 6k line .csv file with latest python3 and matplotlib. The slow part was `plt.show()`  as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51567812/7901146) answer, plotting large unoptimized data set is slow with `matplotlib` .

Answer (score 0):

Plotting can be a significant bottleneck, particularly in matplotlib but should not be with your example.  The quick test below is less than 1s on my machine including creation of the csv file.  Delay might be else where including imports, reading from remote source, etc.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time


def main():
    start = time.time()
    make_test_csv()
    plot_file()
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Duration: {end - start}')


def make_test_csv():
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(6000, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
    df.to_csv('test_data.csv')


def plot_file():
    input_file = 'test_data.csv'
    sample_data = pd.read_csv(input_file, names=["A", "B"], header=None)
    plt.plot(sample_data.A, sample_data.B)
    plt.title("File name: " + input_file)
    plt.xlabel("time scale x / date & time")
    plt.ylabel("quality scale y in %")
    plt.show()
```

The matplotlib user guide provides recommendations regarding [performance](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/users/explain/performance.html).  Using the *fast* plotting style might help.

```
import matplotlib.style as mplstyle
mplstyle.use('fast')
```

Comment: I tried your code.
It is really fast, compared to my code.
Now, I used your csv in my plotting code.
It plotted the same speed like in your app.
Then I tried my log.csv file to plot through your code, and it was also slow like in my code.
So, there is maybe a problem with my log file?
But I don't see any problems with my csv.
BTW. How can I share with you my csv file?